# Flutter web - send Uint8List to server

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I record audio on the web with flutter_sound package. The recorded file is saved in the `blob:https://myapp.com/ae64c7...` path.

Now I want to upload this file to server.

When I use `MultipartFile` I get the following error:

```
MultipartFile is only supported where dart:io is available
```

After researching, I realized that I have to send this file to the server as `Uint8List` in Flutter Web
How can I send this file to the server?

My current code:

```
        XFile file = XFile(recordedFilePath);
        Uint8List content = await file.readAsBytes();
        var dioo = Dio();
        response = await dioo.post(Endpoints.uploadUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XFile file = XFile(recordedFilePath);
Uint8List content = await file.readAsBytes();

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "file": MultipartFile.fromBytes(content, filename: "recordedFile.mp3")
});

Response response = await Dio().post(
  Endpoints.uploadUrl,
  data: formData,
  options: Options(
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  )
);
```